# Need to close program to see datagrid changes after making a search query and update the results

Tags: vb.net

I execute the search query and after that i want to update the results but datagridview doesnt update, need to close and reopen to see the results.
Can anyone help? dont know if the problem is in the update button or the search

Update button

```
   Call cn()

   Dim teste As String


  teste = "UPDATE CARROS SET processo = '" & processo & "', estado = '" & estado & "', tecnico = '" & tecnico & "', data = #" & data & "# , localizacao = '" & localizacao & "', [Pedido/PI] = '" & pedido & "'
        WHERE Código = " & codigo



            updatee = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(teste, connection)
            updatee.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Actualizado com sucesso")
            connection.Close()
            CARROSTableAdapter1.Fill(STOCKDataSet1.CARROS)
```

SEARCH Button

```
  Dim locali As String

    Call cn()

    'Se não tem valor Erro
    If pesqtxt.Text = "" Then

        MsgBox("Introduz um Valor")
    Else
        locali = pesqtxt.Text


        'Codigo SQL
        sql = "Select *
               FROM CARROS
               WHERE (processo LIKE '%" & locali & "%') OR
                     (estado LIKE '%" & locali & "%') OR
                     (data Like '%" & locali & "%') OR
                     (localizacao Like '%" & locali & "%') OR
                     (tecnico Like '%" & locali & "%')"

        oledbAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        oledbAdapter.Fill(ds)
        CARROSDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        CARROSTableAdapter1.Update(STOCKDataSet1.CARROS)
        CARROSTableAdapter1.Fill(STOCKDataSet1.CARROS)
        connection.Close()
```

Comment: What if you have an error? Who closes he connection? Connections need to be disposed in addition to closed so they can release unmanaged objects.

Comment: Do not concatenate strings to build sql command text. Use parameters. You are risking sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the Search code goes, you cannot find out if a String is "Like" as Date.

Using...End Using blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. Keep you database objects local and open connections as late as possible anc close as soon as possible.

```
Private Sub UpdateDatabse()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE CARROS SET processo = @processo, estado = @estado, tecnico = @tecnico, data = @data , localizacao = @localizacao, [Pedido/PI] = @pedido WHERE Código =  @codigo", cn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@processo", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = processo
                .Add("@estado", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = estado
                .Add("@tecnico", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = tecnico
                .Add("@data", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(Data)
                .Add("@localizacao", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = localizacao
                .Add("@peido", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pedido
                .Add("@codigo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = codigo
            End With
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Actualizado com sucesso")
    CARROSTableAdapter1.Fill(STOCKDataSet1.CARROS)  'No way for me to check this
End Sub

Private Sub Search(locali As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select *
           FROM CARROS
           WHERE (processo LIKE @processo) OR
                 (estado LIKE @estado) OR
                 (localizacao Like @localizacao) OR
                 (tecnico Like @tecnico);", cn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@processo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" & locali & "%"
                .Add("@estado", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" & locali & "%"
                .Add("@localizacao", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" & locali & "%"
                .Add("@tecnico", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" & locali & "%"
            End With
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        CARROSDataGridView.DataSource = Nothing
        CARROSDataGridView.DataSource = dt
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No matching records found")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Se não tem valor Erro
    If pesqtxt.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Introduz um Valor")
        Return
    End If
    Search(pesqtxt.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: ty for your help, it didnt solve the problem, but i learn a lot from what you post and it help me fix one problem, refresh the datagrid after making another search, so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Refresh option on the grid after you have loaded the updated data.

```
    CARROSDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    CARROSTableAdapter1.Update(STOCKDataSet1.CARROS)
    CARROSTableAdapter1.Fill(STOCKDataSet1.CARROS)
    CARROSDataGridView.Refresh
```

Comment: didnt work, put it there "connection.Close()  CARROSTableAdapter1.Fill(STOCKDataSet1.CARROS)
CARROSDataGridView.Refresh()", and still the same problem, after search it doesnt update, need to reopen the form to see changes

Comment: What if you try resetting the datasource?

Comment: can u give me a exemple?, im still new at vb :/